Laplace's Equation on an annulus with Dirichlet/Neumann boundary conditions
We're given general solutions to Laplace's equation of the form $ \phi(r,\theta) = Ar^\alpha \cos(\beta \theta) $, and we're asked to find specific solutions given the boundary conditions: $ a \leq r \leq b, \hspace{3ex} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}(a,\theta) = 0, \hspace{3ex} \phi(b,\theta) = \lambda \cos(5\theta) $ where $ \lambda $ is a constant.
Attempt:
If $ \phi $ satisfies Laplace's equation, then we know:
$$
\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \bigg( r \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} \bigg) + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial \theta^2} = 0
$$
If we plug in the given form of $ \phi $ into Laplace's equation, we get the equation:
$$
A(\alpha^2 - \beta^2) r^{\alpha - 2} \cos(\beta \theta) = 0
$$
This equation is satisfied when $ \alpha = \pm \beta $. However since $ \beta $ only shows up in the cosine function, and since cosine is an even function, then we can set $ \alpha = \beta $, leaving us with solutions of the form: $ \phi(r,\theta) = A r^\alpha \cos(\alpha \theta) $.
If we apply the $ \phi(b,\theta) $ boundary condition, we get the equation:
$$
\phi(b,\theta) = Ab^\alpha \cos(\alpha \theta) = \lambda \cos(5\theta)
$$
From this equation, we get that $ \alpha = \pm 5 $, and $ A = \lambda/b^\alpha $. So at this point the solution has the form:
$$
\phi(r,\theta) = \frac{\lambda}{b^\alpha} r^\alpha \cos(\alpha \theta)
$$
Then applying the $ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n} $ boundary condition, we first explicitly write the derivative in the boundary condition:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial n} = \mathbf{n} \cdot \nabla \phi = -\mathbf{e}_r \cdot \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \mathbf{e}_r + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \mathbf{e}_\theta \bigg) = - \frac{\partial}{\partial r}
$$
We then apply the boundary condition:
$$ -\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}(a,\theta) = - \frac{\lambda}{b^\alpha} \alpha a^{\alpha - 1} \cos(\alpha \theta) = 0 
$$
Since we know $ \alpha = \pm 5 $, the only way this equation can be true is if $ \cos(\alpha \theta) = 0 $. But this is only true for specific values of $ \theta $. Does this then mean that solutions only exist for specific values of $ \theta $? This feels wrong as we're told to find solutions on the entire $ a \leq r \leq b $ domain.

You need a solution of the form $$\phi(r, \theta)=(Ar^{\alpha}+Br^{-\alpha})\cos(\alpha\theta).$$

Dirichlet and Neumann, not Robin.

We were specifically asked to work with solutions of the form $ \phi(r,\theta) = Ar^\alpha \cos(\beta \theta) $. We're not allowed to change the structure of the solution in this problem

What @Gonçalo means is that since you got $\alpha=\pm \beta$ then the linear combination of $\phi(\beta)$ and $\phi(-\beta)$ satisfies Laplace's equation too (as long as $\beta\neq 0$). Basically,
$$(Ar^\beta+Br^{-\beta})\cos(\beta\theta)$$
satisfies that PDE too.
Therefore, using $\phi(b,\theta)=\lambda\cos(5\theta)$ we get
$$\color{blue}{(Ab^\beta+Bb^{-\beta})}\color{red}{\cos(\beta\theta)}=\color{blue}{\lambda}\color{red}{\cos(5\theta)}$$
By comparing similar terms we conclude $\beta=\pm5$ and that
$$Ab^5+Bb^{-5}=\lambda$$
In addition, from the other BC, $\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial\boldsymbol n}(a,\theta)=-\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial r}(a,\theta)=0$, we get
$$(5Aa^4-5Ba^{-6})\cos(5\theta)=0$$
If we want this to hold $\forall\theta$, then
$$5Aa^4-5Ba^{-6}=0$$
Namely we have to solve
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
b^5 & b^{-5}\\
5a^4 & -5a^{-6}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A\\
B
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Its solutions are
$$A=\dfrac{\lambda b^5}{b^{10}+a^{10}}\qquad \& \qquad  B=\dfrac{\lambda a^{10}b^5}{b^{10}+a^{10}}$$
